# Programmatically add functions to the root node object

Tags: javascript, node.js

In regular browser js, we can do this:

```
window["fname"] = function(){ /* do something */ };
```

then we can call `fname` where ever we want - it is now a global function. Is it possible to do a similar thing in node, where we add functions to a certain object and they can be called as is in the rest of the file:

```
root["fname"] = function(){ /* do something */ };
fname();
```

I'm not looking for a something that acts globally over all files, just something that would keep the "global namespace pollution" in this file that I can call all of these functions as is, without resorting to `obj.fname`.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691453/javascript-function-change-variables-scope

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, he can use **with**, but its **evil** - 
http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/ ;]

Comment: Nope, `with` is not an option as it does not allow access to other variables which do not need that prefix. See [my code](https://github.com/CRogers/coml) to understand what I was trying to do and how it relates to this question.

Comment: oh, i see what you want to do... hmmm, i have no idea how to it ^^ Maybe you could try look into codebase of Firebug debugger?

Comment: It works now :p You just need to wrap the "view" in a self running function.

Comment: Could you post some example here, what exactly you done to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT (for clarity):

As far my test showed - you can't access local scope of a module. It is (or is like) closure, and you cant programatically acces its scope. So your best bet is **global** (aka **root**) object, which keeps global vars, BUT it is the same for whole app (so every module has acces to it).

So, the best you is making shortcuts each time:

```
var foo = myModule.foo;
var boo = myAnotherModule.boo;
```

---

Use 'global' as namespace:

```
global['foo'] = function(){ console.log('foo'); }; // same as global.foo = ...

foo() //prints 'foo' to console
```

More here:

http://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/jb4dy/adding_to_the_global_namespace_in_nodejs/

Comment: See the related documentation: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/globals.html#global . And `global.foo = ...` is just the same as `global['foo'] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

`root` was the object I wanted:

```
root["foo"] = function(){ /* blah */ }
foo();
```

Comment: Yeah, but `root` is the same object as `global` (and `GLOBAL`). You can try executing `root===global` or look at output of `console.log(root)`, there you have `global: [Circular]` which states for self refference.